# All array elements are not assigned to model

Tags: javascript, arrays, express, sapui5

I have the array from my expressjs which looks like below. And I am assigning this array to model in my frontend framework openui5. But only the first 100 elements of array i.e [0-99] are being loaded into model and all other array elements are not considered i.e [100-520], why is this and how can I make sure that all array elements are loaded into my model?

[image]

Below is the code used to load model.

```
 onAfterRendering: function () {
        var that = this;
        var businessQuery= $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '/getAllBusinesses',          
            dataType: "json"
        });
        $.when(businessQuery).done(function (oBusinesses) {
            that.businessModel= new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            that.businessModel.setData(oBusinesses[0].franchisees); //fracnchisees is array of 520 elements
            that.getView().setModel(that.businessModel, 'businessModel');

        });
        $.when(businessQuery).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(errorThrown);
        });    
    },
```

My view where the model is bound to a table looks as below,

```
 var oBusinessListColumn = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: [                
                new sap.m.Button({
                    icon: '{businessModel>picture/data/url}',
                    text: '{businessModel>name}',
                    type: sap.m.ButtonType.Transparent,
                    press: [oController.showBusiness, oController]
                }),               
                new sap.m.Button({
                    icon: 'img/Revember32_32.png',
                    text: {
                        path: 'businessModel>presentInRevember',
                        formatter: jQuery.proxy(oController.formatPresentInRevember, oController)
                    },
                    type: sap.m.ButtonType.Emphasized,
                    press: [oController.invitePressed, oController]
                })
            ]
        });

        var oBusinessTable = new sap.m.Table('js-myBusiness-oBusinessTable', {
            fixedLayout: false,
            columns: [
                new sap.m.Column({

                    header: new sap.m.Label({text: 'Business'})
                }),
                new sap.m.Column({

                    header: new sap.m.Label({text: 'Status'})
                })
            ],
            layoutData: new sap.ui.layout.GridData({span: "L12 M12 S12"})
        }).addStyleClass('css-alignHorizontalCenter css-sTopBottomMargin card');
        oBusinessTable.bindAggregation('items', 'businessModel>/', oBusinessListColumn);
```

**And when the table is rendered I see only first 100 elements of model and not full 520 elements.**

Regards,
Chidan

Comment: I'm confused. You showed a screenshot of an array that does include the 520 entries, is that not the array you're working with? or, are you saying openui5 is only reading the first 100 from the array (which would indicate that node.js and express have nothing to do with this)

Comment: may be opeui5 is just reading the first 100 elements of the array but I am not sure; when I assign the data to the model like below  --> businessModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
            businessModel .setData(object[0].franchisee);

Comment: I am not sure if it is related to openui5 or to javascript in general. And why is the display in debugger splitting array by 100s?

Comment: That's just how chrome displays large arrays.

Comment: side-note, you don't need `$.when`. `businessQuery.done(fn).fail(fn)` will work just as well.

Comment: I didn't test this, but does using setSizeLimit(1000) on the model change anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phew, got it working. Have to set properties growing: true, growingScrollToLoad: true, on Table which are defined on ListBase which is extended by Table.

Comment: I dont know who marked my answer down, but whoever marked it down doesnt really understand the question or got his concept wrong, :( furious

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the size limit beyond the default of 100 using [`setSizeLimit`](https://openui5nightly.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.model.Model/methods/setSizeLimit):

```
oModel.setSizeLimit(999999);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome's `console.log()` shows the array grouped by 100 items. At the `length` property you can see, that the array contains all 520 items.

Comment: Yes, but why is my model not loading all 520 elements but only first 100?

Comment: Please share the code, which is used to create the model.

Comment: Have you called `setSizeLimit()` on the model?

Comment: @ Martin Lantzsch, I just updated the code, no I have not called setSizeLimit() on model

Comment: How do you notice, that not all elements are loaded into the model? In the openui5 code is no hardcoded limit or view buffer (except you are using oData).

Comment: I bind the model to the table items with bind aggregations and then I see only first 100 items in the table.. now adding code for binding into table too..

Comment: You could try passing `count` property to `ColumnListItem` which inherits from `ListItemBase` as defined here: https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListItemBase.html#constructor

Comment: you mean to say counter : int of ListItemBase ? but how will this affect number of item being displayed?

Comment: Sorry, missed that the itembase represents a single row, this does not affect the count of shown records. In the documentation of table is stated "the recommended limit of table rows is 100(based on 4 columns) to assure proper performance. To improve initial rendering on large tables, use the "growing" feature". Have you tried this? https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/api/symbols/sap.m.Table.html

Comment: I think I have to try the growing feature as you said, because now I am sure that 520 records are indeed in businessModel just that not displayed in table. I could see this in debug mode ---> that.businessModel.oData: Array[520]

Comment: phew, got it working. Have to set properties  growing: true,
            growingScrollToLoad: true, on Table which are defined on ListBase which is extended by Table. Thanks for the pointer to ListBase

Comment: Yeah, nice! No problem